# DB Error: no such field on Profile/Page link

Tags: profile, 4.7

I'm making a public members directory using using Civi 4.7.6 on Joomla! 3.5.1. Member profiles includes 3 small sets of custom fields. One of those sets is  multivalue (`civicrm_value_certifica_es_pmi_4`) and other one includes a file field (`foto_16`). Everything is going fine until I added both a file AND an entry to the multivalue field and tried to drill down to the contact individual page from the directory/profile listing page. Then, I got a DB Error and looking at the Log I saw the following:

> [debug_info] => **SELECT** foto_16 **FROM civicrm_value_dados_pessoais_2**
>   where entity_id = 563 AND **civicrm_value_certifica_es_pmi_4**.id = 3
>   [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column
>   '**civicrm_value_certifica_es_pmi_4**.id' in 'where clause']

It looks like (I'm not a DB pro...) the **SELECT** is trying to use two tables (`civicrm_value_dados_pessoais_2`, `civicrm_value_certifica_es_pmi_4`), but only one (`civicrm_value_dados_pessoais_2`) was loaded in **FROM** statement.

Does it make sense?

If so, does it looks like a bug or can it be something I messed up?

Thank you!